# Axis 1.4 Corba module Date format and TImezone locked

Tags: timezone, axis, corba

We're using Axis's Corba module (Axis 1.4) to convert Corba requests/responses automatically to webservices. The issue is that the output XML has always the dateTime fields transcribed to UTC zone and with the following format 2021-01-21T21:12:00.000Z

Unfortunatelly we're just using Corba module as a translator, we're not doing any custom / inhouse coding.

Is there any way to either:

1. Keep the date on the original timezone (as it is on the Corba response)
2. At least have a date on a different format